# Sublime text: possible to replace characters within a 'find' selection?

Tags: replace, sublimetext2

I've got a long list with html code that looks like this:

```
<li class="parentCat"><a href="https://www.website.com/category" name="left.navi.category.1:category cars"><strong>Cars</strong></a></li>
<li class="parentCat"><a href="https://www.website.com/category" name="left.navi.category.1:category trains"><strong>Trains</strong></a></li>
```

I need to replace the space within the left.navi.category with a dash "-". So instead of name="left.navi.category.1:**category cars** it needs to become name="left.navi.category.1:**category-cars**.

Is there any way to replace characters within a search selection? Since the document is +- 2000 lines (all with the same makeup as the example above) I'd like to find a way to automate this.

I already found a way to find all the lines with the left.navi.category by using CTRL+H and then look for "name="left.navi.category.1:[^<]+". But I'm not sure how to replace the " " with a "-", is it possible to find and replace within a find?

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> click on [Regular Expressions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0W7Gj.jpg) and Replace

```
category.1:category ([a-z]*)"
```

with

```
category.1:category-$1"
```